# How to reload child page with new data after the data has been changed from same page in IONIC v2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am a newbie to ionic v2. I am using http post service to post the data and returning to the inventory.ts's .subscribe() method(refer below code). I am on inventory page that is child page of subcategory page and its further child page of category page. Category page is set as root page. 
When i use location.reload() it goes to the root page. I need to reload the inventory page whic contains the new data. In the given image count inside -50+ will be 50-50 ie. 0, after submit is clicked and alterStock function is called. so i need to refresh it with -0+ count.

> inventory-provider.ts

```
alterStock(stockRelatedData) {

if (stockRelatedData.departmentID === null || stockRelatedData.itemID === null || stockRelatedData.stock === null) {
  return Observable.throw("Please insert details");
} else {
  return Observable.create(observer => {

    let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: headers
    });

        // TODO: Encode the values using encodeURIComponent().
    var link = 'http://ims/api/inventory/alterstock?api_token='+ stockRelatedData.apiToken;
    var data = JSON.stringify({department_id: stockRelatedData.departmentID, item_id: stockRelatedData.itemID, stock: stockRelatedData.stock, api_token: stockRelatedData.apiToken, location_id: stockRelatedData.locationID, user_id: stockRelatedData.userID});
    this.http.post(link, data, options)
    .subscribe(result => {

        this.data = result;
        this.data = JSON.parse(this.data._body);

        let access = this.data.status;
        observer.next(access);
        observer.complete();
    }, error => {
        console.log("Oooops!");
    });

  });
}
```

}

> inventory.ts

```
this.inventoryService.alterStock(this.stockRelatedData).subscribe(allowed => {
            if (allowed) {
              setTimeout(() => {
              this.loading.dismiss();
              // here i need to reload this child page with new data
              });
            } else {
              this.showError("Access Denied");
            }
          },
          error => {
            this.showError(error);
          });
```

[image: [enter image description here]]

Comment: did u try using  this.navCtrl.push(yourRequiredPage); ?
 You Also need to use get call from your server , and then u will get the latest data on same page and then u may use this this.navCtrl.push(yourRequiredPage);

Comment: @devanshsadhotra I am on this items/inventory page(image shown above). I tried this.navCtrl.push(this); but it did nothing. Lets supose if i assign 5 items to restaurant department and click submit. then its count chages to 50 minus 5 i.e 45 and i have to click back button and then click on the category to get the updated data. but i want it to display it without going back button. any Idea? how to do that?

Comment: You are making post call to your server !! m i right ?

Comment: if yes, then it means your data is being stored in your database. and now you need to get data.

Comment: @devanshsadhotra yea, this.http.post(link, data, options). in inventory-provider.ts. yes exactly i need it from db

Comment: now to update your values dynamically , all you need is to do one thing , 
 after this line of code  observer.complete();
 make your get call to fetch your data. ie you are getting the data within the same function of posting data

Comment: @devanshsadhotra i call 'this.getInventories(this.navParams.get('catID'));' in my inventory.ts file to get the items/inventories. Are u saying that i  shuld make another call next to observer.complete() in my inventory-provider.ts file. Please explain bit more how to do it?

Comment: make the same call as you are doing in this.getInventories just below observer.complete() , because this is the point your post call is getting completed. So , practically speaking after the complete post call you need to get the data that you have posted

Comment: or should i call this.getInventories(this.navParams.get('catID')); in inventory.ts after this.loading.dismiss();?

Comment: @devanshsadhotra ok let me just try

Comment: this.loading.dismiss() i myself don't use at all , instead i prefer button diabling till i get response. "this.loading.dismiss" sometimes stuck within the api call

Comment: ok i solved it by calling getInventories function in inventory.ts.i did it few hour ago once but it didn't work at that time. i dont know why.

Comment: cheers :D , carry on

Comment: Solution: in inventories.ts file call the items again                      this.loading.dismiss();                      
this.getInventories(this.navParams.get('catID'));
this.selectedItem = 0; thanks anyway.

Comment: anytime :) mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calling same function , once you make any event related to inventory updation , call same function which let you show them  .

That should solve the case !

**Note: Two way binding should have worked there , but in case it does not work , make it forcefully!**